# DataViewGrid synchronization C#

Tags: c#, .net, dataview

I am new in C# and have a requirement where a DataViewGrid have fixed rows and three columns. Each column’s data is coming from different source and three threads are running simultaneously to receive it. Now, is it possible to update these columns i.e.
Column one by thread one 
Column two by thread two
Column three by thread three
Without using any synchronization object?
If this is not possible then I will create three DataViewGrid and which will be updated by individual threads.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Windows Forms or WPF?
In general you can use something called Bindings. In WinForms there normally is a property "**DataContext**" on the UI-controls. You can update that property from other threads. You can then control which column is matched to which property of the List or array you provided to the DataContext.
In WPF there are observable collection. You also map the control to a Property and then update that property from one of your threads.

It is hard to give you more advice because I am lacking information on which technology you are using and which architecture (MVC, MVVM, ...).
If you need more help please update your question and provide us with more information.

Comment: We will get huge data and have to update it every .1 seconds. Therefore i like to update only cell as updating he entire list will refresh the complete datagrid and eventually will be a time consuming task.

Comment: Then check following tutorial on how to use databinding in Windows Forms: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html           Hope this helps

Comment: If you use large amount of data use "paging". That way the large amount of data has no affect on performance.

Comment: Thanks for new approach. Could please give a brief/link to implement the paging in DataGrid?

Comment: Check this page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211551/A-Simple-way-for-Paging-in-DataGridView-in-WinForm

Comment: @CrazyC did any of these answers answer your question? If yes please consider accepting one as official answer. Your question will appear as "open" until you have closed it.

Comment: I haven't got answer and right now this work is on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but I don't like it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    DataGridViewRow newRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow);
  }

  FillThread[] t = new FillThread[3];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    t[i] = new FillThread(this.dataGridView1, i);
  }
}


class FillThread
{
    struct param_t
    {
        public DataGridView TheGrid;
        public int Type;
    }

    private Thread _worker;




    public FillThread(DataGridView theGrid, int type)
    {
        _worker = new Thread(ThreadProc);

        param_t param = new param_t();
        param.TheGrid = theGrid;
        param.Type = type;

        _worker.Start(param);
    }

    public void ThreadProc(object data)
    {
        param_t param = (param_t)data;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            param.TheGrid.Rows[i].Cells[param.Type].Value = i;
        }



    }
}
```